# First file loaded in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm preparing for an interview and i'm new to cakephp, while searching in the internet i came across this questions...
"What is the first file that gets loaded when you run a application using cakephp?"
Answer: 
Interviewer : what is the first file that gets loaded when you run a application using cakephp., 
Candidate : can you change that file.
Interviewer: yes
bootstrap.php , yes it can be changed , either through index.php , or through htaccess
Which file is loaded first, if that particular file is not changable.
I tried to find out the answer, but couldn't get it.
Can any one help me on this please?

Comment: I'm seriously having problem trying to understand what you are asking here... The answer maybe `index.php` if I understand your question correctly

Comment: I found that interview question in this link "http://cakephp-interview-questions.blogspot.in/".

Comment: I stopped reading at `they were fat not only physically but mentally as well.` :s...

Comment: The answer is bootstrap.php file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very first file being loaded is `index.php` (as per the `.htaccess` rewrite rules) in the webroot folder, which will add CakePHP's core in the include path

**CakePHP 1.3**

```
if (!defined('CORE_PATH')) {
        if (function_exists('ini_set') && ini_set('include_path', CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH . PATH_SEPARATOR . ROOT . DS . APP_DIR . DS . PATH_SEPARATOR . ini_get('include_path'))) {
            define('APP_PATH', null);
            define('CORE_PATH', null);
        } else {
            define('APP_PATH', ROOT . DS . APP_DIR . DS);
            define('CORE_PATH', CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH . DS);
        }
    }
    if (!include(CORE_PATH . 'cake' . DS . 'bootstrap.php')) {
        trigger_error("CakePHP core could not be found.  Check the value of CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH in APP/webroot/index.php.  It should point to the directory containing your " . DS . "cake core directory and your " . DS . "vendors root directory.", E_USER_ERROR);
    }
```

**CakePHP 2.1**

```
if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
        if (function_exists('ini_set')) {
            ini_set('include_path', ROOT . DS . 'lib' . PATH_SEPARATOR . ini_get('include_path'));
        }
        if (!include('Cake' . DS . 'bootstrap.php')) {
            $failed = true;
        }
    } else {
        if (!include(CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH . DS . 'Cake' . DS . 'bootstrap.php')) {
            $failed = true;
        }
    }
```

It then includes `bootstrap.php` in both case.

So the answer is : `index.php` and you **shall not modify it** (unless you are in some [particular cases](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html)), then `app/Config/bootstrap.php` and you [**may modify it**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#bootstrapping-cakephp).

Comment: I should point out that the `bootstrap.php` file that is being loaded in Jeremie's example is actually Cake's _internal_ copy of the file (now days typically at [`Vendor/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5.4/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php) when Cake is installed via Composer), [which itself loads](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5.4/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php#L175) your own `Config/bootstrap.php`.

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful:

As of cake 2.6 here is the order of config files to be loaded

```
core.php
database.php
bootstrap.php
routes.php
```